# HTML formatting tags not working

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to using some simple inline styling, but the bold won't work.  I am using a CSS reset.  Does anyone know why?

HTML:

```
<p class="line10"><b>Guidance Resources:</b> Call 888-999-6768.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.line10 {
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Here is the CSS reset cod...............................................................................

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    RESET
\*------------------------------------*/
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
    v2.0b1 | 201101 
    NOTE:WORK IN PROGRESS
    USE WITH CAUTION AND TEST WITH ABANDON */

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,
a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,
del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,
small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,
b,u,i,center,
dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,
fieldset,form,label,legend,
table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,
article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,
time,mark,audio,video{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{
    display:block;
}
body{
    line-height:1;
}
ol,ul{
    /*list-style:none;*/
}
blockquote,q{
    quotes:none;
}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,
q:before,q:after{
    content:’’;
    content:none;
}
/* remember to define visible focus styles! 
:focus{
    outline:?????;
} */

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins{
    text-decoration:none;
}
del{
    text-decoration:line-through;
}

table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine according to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mansfield/9FE24/ What browser are you using?

Comment: Are you using some kind of reset CSS which sets b's font-weight to normal?

Comment: This is not an example of inline styling. This is presumably "embedded" styling, but it's impossibly to tell without knowing where the CSS lives.

Comment: Yes I am using a CSS reset

Comment: I would use `<strong>` tags instead

Comment: Can you post *all* of your relevant code? What you posted is 100% correct.

Comment: Which CSS reset? You may need to re-define the styling for a bold tag.

Comment: to add bold to your element use css font-weight:bold;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your CSS reset:

```
b, strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Make sure that your stylesheets are inserted after the reset.

Comment: That worked!  I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes :P  THANKS

Comment: You're welcome. Why in 7 minutes? Some strange Stackoverflow restriction?

Comment: Yep OverflowStack restriction acutally

Answer (score 0):

So this is caused by

```
font: inherit;
```

line which overrides `font-weight`. You could remove it or manually *rereset* required styles for `<b>` tags.

I'd also suggest using [`Normalize.css`](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) instead of your clumsy reset.